# calendar.add returns strange dates

Tags: android, calendar

I'm trying to simply add a n-number to the current date by using:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(); // today 12.05.2014
calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 2); // expected 14.05.2014 --> returns 01.06.2014
```

Unfortunately it does not return the expected date.

Using `calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 0);` returns the current date. Now I'm totally confused. Did i oversee something?

Here is my Log:

```
java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1401469591003,areFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,
zone=Europe/Berlin,firstDayOfWeek=2,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=4,ERA=1,

**YEAR=2014,**
**MONTH=4,**

WEEK_OF_YEAR=22,
WEEK_OF_MONTH=5,

**DAY_OF_MONTH=30,** // I would initially expect 12
DAY_OF_YEAR=150,

DAY_OF_WEEK=6,

DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=5,
AM_PM=1,HOUR=7,HOUR_OF_DAY=19,MINUTE=6,SECOND=31,MILLISECOND=3,ZONE_OFFSET=3600000,DST_OFFSET=3600000]
```

AFTER adding 2

```
java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1401642391003,areFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,
zone=Europe/Berlin,firstDayOfWeek=2,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=4,ERA=1,

**YEAR=2014,**
**MONTH=5,**

WEEK_OF_YEAR=22,
WEEK_OF_MONTH=1,

**DAY_OF_MONTH=1,**
DAY_OF_YEAR=152,

DAY_OF_WEEK=1,

DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=1,
AM_PM=1,HOUR=7,HOUR_OF_DAY=19,MINUTE=6,SECOND=31,MILLISECOND=3,ZONE_OFFSET=3600000,DST_OFFSET=3600000]
```

**UPDATE**

Found the misterous error:
As I created a calendar object by:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
```

I wanted to add (add()) multiple times a new date inside a for statement.

```
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, i);
```

Inside this statement, I added a new date (calendar.add(i)), which does not worked. After I moved the constructor inside the for statement, all calculations are correct now.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, i);
```

I really don't understand this behavior - but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this **add(Calendar.DATE, 1);**

Comment: resulting in the same behavior. Based on the Doc ([link](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html)) it will internally use the same static number (5)